# How to respond to 'click' instead of 'swipe' on mobile in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, on a mobile page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
        /* Do something */
    });
});
```

works fine, but on mobile devices it's called both for click on links and on swipe (that is touching the link, scrolling and lifting the finger). How can I modify this to be called only on click?

I tried 'tap', 'click' and doesn't seem to work, nor I can find a good list of all the possibile events fired on mobile...

Comment: that is the link for jquery mobile events https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: Yes, jquery mobile, but I can use only classical jquery. I think 'click' and 'touchend' belong to the classical version. (Indeed in my case 'tap' doesn't work, and 'touchend' is not on this list)

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a').on('vclick', function(e) {
        /* Do something */
    });
});
```

Comment: Since I had to look it up, it's a "virtual click" and seems to be exactly what OP is looking for https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Comment: yep , i remember i had this problem one day

Comment: not working :( maybe this depends by the fact the link is on a menu? I'm trying something now and I noticed that this "$('a').click(function() " is called but only the second time you click on a menu item

Comment: yea, it's jquery mobile. No way to do this in classical jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must recognize mobile or pc after that decide which type of event use.

example how you can recognize device [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: I can recognize the device, how this is connected to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

On mobile devices, it seems that the first click on a menu is taken as an hover instead of a click, so the solution in my case was

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a').hover(function(e) {
        /* Do something */
    });
});
```